# how do install python 2.7.2 on ubuntuk with postgresql?

Tags: python

I want to install python 2.7.2.tgz on Ubuntu, downloaded from http://python.org/download/.

so, what the next step?

Comment: I would start by reading the README file.

Comment: You might also find this helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/search.html?q=Installation&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with Python installed by default, you don't need install any .tgz file downloaded from http://python.org/download/

The library for access postgresql in Python called "psycopg"

See: psycopg docs here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/

To install psycopg, you need to first install the build dependencies:

Make the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev python-dev python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install setuptools -U
```

After, install from ubuntu packages repository

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

or, install latest version from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org)

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```